# Azure Cache for large data set

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-caching, azure-cloud-services

How to cache large data set (from azure database) in azure cloud service ?.Can i use table storage as cache?

Data insertion and updation is at high frequency.
I need to generate multiple graph on same page in real time what will be the best approach to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure offers its own cache service. You can learn more about it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn386094.aspx

> Azure Managed Cache Service provides a way for you to perform caching
>   that helps you build fast, scalable applications in Microsoft Azure
>   through a secure, dedicated cache. A secure, dedicated cache is
>   created for you in the region of your choice and you have total
>   control over the cache, guaranteeing isolation of your business
>   critical data.

Comment: right now i am using azure in role cache. Can i do sharding for large data set. Because it supports max object size 8mb

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions available for caching in azure. Some provided by Azure itself are azure in-role caching and azure Redis cache. However each caching solution provided by azure comes with some limitations.

[NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache), a mature caching solutions in .Net caching is also available for Azure. NCache is a high performance, distributed caching solutions with a rich set of features. It also supports Object Query Language, an SQL like language to perform selection and aggregate functions on in-memory data. You can start from here: http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/azure-index.html